# Error starting modern compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, compiler-construction, ant

In my servlet , I m using Tomcat 5.0 and JRE is 1.5.0 but it is giving error when I click on the URL .
As when I created a war file of my project and deployed in tomcat than it is working fine . It means that only problem with my eclipse configuration

ERROR IS : -

```
Apr 5, 2010 3:20:22 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler generateClass
SEVERE: Javac exception 
Error starting modern compiler
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:69)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:942)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:764)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:382)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:472)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:511)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:295)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:61)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Target overrides final method .
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1634)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1307)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1189)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:42)
    ... 40 more
--- Nested Exception ---
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:61)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:942)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:764)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:382)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:472)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:511)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:295)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:929)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:160)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:577)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Target overrides final method .
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1634)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1307)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1189)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:42)
    ... 40 more
Apr 5, 2010 3:20:22 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler generateClass
SEVERE: Env: Compile: javaFileName=/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/SampleSaloni//org/apache/jsp/page\form_jsp.java
    classpath=/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/classes/;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/ant-launcher.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/ant.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/commons-el.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/commons-pool-1.2.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/jasper-compiler.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/jasper-runtime.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/jsp-api.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/naming-common.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/naming-factory.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/naming-java.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/naming-resources.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/tools.jar;D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\SampleSaloni;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/classes/;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/ant-launcher.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/ant.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/commons-el.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/commons-pool-1.2.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/jasper-compiler.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/jasper-runtime.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/jsp-api.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/naming-common.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/naming-factory.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/naming-java.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/naming-resources.jar;/D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/SampleSaloni/WEB-INF/lib/tools.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/classes/;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/ant-launcher.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/ant.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/commons-el.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/commons-pool-1.2.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/jasper-compiler.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/jasper-runtime.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/jsp-api.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/naming-common.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/naming-factory.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/naming-java.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/naming-resources.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/servlet-api.jar;D:/software setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/common/lib/tools.jar;/D:/software%20setups/jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28/bin/bootstrap.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.5.0_09/lib/ext/dnsns.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.5.0_09/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.5.0_09/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\bin\bootstrap.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\classes
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\ant-launcher.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\ant.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections-3.1.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\commons-el.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\commons-pool-1.2.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\jasper-compiler.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\jasper-runtime.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\naming-common.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\naming-factory.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\naming-java.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\naming-resources.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\tools.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\SampleSaloni
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\classes
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\ant-launcher.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\ant.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections-3.1.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\commons-el.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\commons-pool-1.2.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\jasper-compiler.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\jasper-runtime.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\naming-common.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\naming-factory.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\naming-java.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\naming-resources.jar
    cp=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SampleSaloni\WEB-INF\lib\tools.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\classes
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\ant-launcher.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\ant.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\commons-collections-3.1.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\commons-dbcp-1.2.1.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\commons-el.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\commons-pool-1.2.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\jasper-compiler.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\jasper-runtime.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\jsp-api.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\naming-common.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\naming-factory.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\naming-java.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\naming-resources.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\servlet-api.jar
    cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\tools.jar
    cp=D:\software%20setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\bin\bootstrap.jar
    cp=C:\Program%20Files\Java\jre1.5.0_09\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
    cp=C:\Program%20Files\Java\jre1.5.0_09\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
    cp=C:\Program%20Files\Java\jre1.5.0_09\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar
    work dir=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\SampleSaloni
    extension dir=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_09\lib\ext
    srcDir=D:\OffViv\JAVA_IDE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\SampleSaloni
    include=org/apache/jsp/page/form_jsp.java

Apr 5, 2010 3:20:22 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler generateClass
SEVERE: Error compiling file: /D:/OffViv/JAVA_IDE/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/SampleSaloni//org/apache/jsp/page\form_jsp.java     [javac] Compiling 1 source file
```

Comment: For future reference, you should format console output as code (indent four spaces, or just select and click the "101/010" icon above the edit window). I've already done this for you in this instance.

Answer (score 9):

I was also getting the same problem while running `ant build`.

Since I was not aware of this term "Error starting modern compiler", so I run command with verbos log option i.e `ant -v build` and finally getting that "Out of memory error" so before applying please increase JRE memory.

So please apply `set ANT_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m`, and then run `ant build`. The issue will get solved.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is shown in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.Target overrides final method .
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1634)
```

The problem is that your 'javac' is incompatible with the runtime, probably because you're running a different java compiler from the one that the JVM has already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed the following:

> cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\naming-resources.jar
>
> cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\servlet-api.jar
>
> **cp=D:\software setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\common\lib\tools.jar**
>
> cp=D:\software%20setups\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\bin\bootstrap.jar
>
> cp=C:\Program%20Files\Java\jre1.5.0_09\lib\ext\dnsns.jar

The VerifyError indicates that the version of the javac compiler being invoked is not compatible with your JDK.  My guess is that the tools.jar from a previous/later JDK version was copied into Tomcat's common/lib directory, and the tools.jar in common/lib is conflicting with the one of the current JDK.

I don't know why tools.jar exists in your common/lib directory, it shouldn't be needed there.  (perhaps it was put there in order to be able to run Tomcat with a JRE instead of a JDK)

Either take it out, or if it really is needed, copy the one from your current JDK you are using to run Tomcat over this one.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to a memory issue. Please increase the memory size:

```
ANT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: or add to your *project.properties* file a line `javac.memoryMaximumSize="2048m"`

Answer (score 0):

Its weird and shouldn't happen. But I was getting same error for one of my project. I added

```
-Xmx1024m
```

at runtime conf and it worked. I understand that this needs to be done for "OutOfMemory issues", but it worked here as well.
Strange..

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MyEclipse (which is not clear), maybe have a look at this [blog post](http://xhye.blogspot.com/2009/09/tomcat-50-error-starting-modern.html). Basically, you may need to align the VM used by Tomcat with the one used inside Eclipse.

Comment: i made the changes as given in the link but still .I m getting same error .

Comment: Tell us which jvm your tomcat is using, and then tell us which jvm your MyEclipse is using.

Comment: blog post is dead link